# how to get line count and line height of textview using thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, textview

I want to expand my view as much that of textview height.Following code works but not perfect. It leaves empty spaces. So please help me how can i meet my requirment.Thank you.

```
private void expand(final View summary) {
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+pos, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    // set Visible
    summary.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


      ((TextView) summary).post(new Runnable() {

           @Override
           public void run() {

            linecnt=((TextView) summary).getLineCount();
            ans=((TextView) summary).getLineHeight();
            //ans=((TextView) summary).getWidth();
            no1=linecnt*ans;
            name();
           }
           private void name() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK "+linecnt*ans, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
          });


    final int widthSpec = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(1,View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
    summary.measure(widthSpec, 300);
    ValueAnimator mAnimator;

    mAnimator = slideAnimator(0,no1, summary);

    mAnimator.start();
}
```

Comment: Sheetal, where exacly it leaves the spaces?

Comment: hello pratt, 
I have relative layout which contains title textview.
Below that relative layout i have textview containing  description about title.
My target is to achieve..
Whenever i click on title textview description textview should expand as much as it have contents.

But it expanding more than its content size.

Comment: summary.measure(widthSpec, 300); what this line means? 300 for size?

Comment: Creates a measure specification based on the supplied size and mode

Comment: Sheetal, in short you want just expand and collapse yout textview..right?

Comment: I think that 300 is the problem, give it value 200 or 100 and check and then let me know please.

Comment: Right pratt, and its working.The only problem is extra space after expanding view

Comment: have you checked with reducing that size from 300 to 100?

Comment: Yes I tried it just now. It doesn't show any effect.

Comment: hmmm okay, can you send me your code? I will import in my IDE and will get back to you.

Comment: I i'll send the xml and java for the same

Comment: send me your whole project zip file dear, so I can import it directly, pratikdasa@gmail.com is my email id.

Answer (score 0):

You could count all '\n' characters + 1 from linecnt.getText()